# Cucumber feature file in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, cucumber, gherkin

I would like to know if it is possible to have an excel spreadsheet that contains Gherkin statements and then convert it to a cucumber feature file. I have looked extensively on the internet and I have not been able to find anything related to this. I did find some forums where it is mentioned that this may not be possible. I am pretty new to cucumber and I would like to know whether it can be done. I also found that with spec-flow (cucumber for .NET) it is possible. But I am using cucumber with Java.
I would appreciate it if someone can give me some guidance regarding this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any tool that support this.

To me, it sounds like you would need a pre-process that extracts the scenarios from their storage in an Excel file.

The answer to your question, "is it possible to have an excel spreadsheet that contains Gherkin statements and then convert it to a cucumber feature file" is yes. But I am not aware of any tool. You probably have to write it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We decided to go to another route with this. But many thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

We have done one implementation where we extracted all the scenarios from JIRA tool. The scenarios were the acceptance criteria and then copied same in Feature file.
To answer your question, we have not done so far, but you may need to write a separate code for same.